# Difference between {a,b} == 2'b10 and a & ~b in verilog

Tags: verilog

I just started to learn verilog and I was trying to create a mealy machine that finds the sequence 1010 so I wrote this:

```
module Find1010(input clk, input in, output reg out);
    reg [1:0]st = 0;
    wire a = {st[0], in} == 2'b10;
    wire b = {st   , in} == 3'b101;
    always @(posedge clk)
    begin
        out  =   a & st[1];
        st   =  {a | b, in};
    end
endmodule
```

and it worked but then i changed the line `wire a = {st[0], in} == 2'b10;`

to `wire a = st[0] & ~in;` and then the output was always 0. why is it happening and what's the difference between `{st[0], in} == 2'b10` and `st[0] & ~in`?

this is the testbench i wrote:

```
module Test;
    reg in = 0, clk = 1;
    wire result;
    initial begin
         #4 in = 1;
         #4 in = 0;
         #2 in = 1;
         #2 in = 0;
         #2 in = 1;
         #2 in = 0;
         #2 in = 1;
         #4 in = 0;
         #2 in = 1;
         #2 in = 0;
         #3 $finish;
    end
    initial forever #1 clk = ~clk;
    always @(negedge clk)
        $display("Input: %b    Output: %b", in , result);
    Find1010 Mealy_Machine(
        .clk(clk),
        .in(in),
        .out(result)
    );
endmodule
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no difference (except when X's are involved)

The problem is you have a race condition in your testbench. You need to use non-blocking assignments to `in`. Or change clock period so changes to `in` do not fall on a clock edge.

Comment: and here is a couple of other things that you should change: 1) use non-blocking in your _dut_ module for `out` and `st`.  2) use `always @*` for $display in your testbench,.

Comment: @Serge, Agree with 1), Disagree with 2), too much output for larger testbenches. Only for specific debug cases - it would not help here.

Comment: @dave_59 why does it matter if it's blocking or non-blocking. `st` doesn't use the value of `out` so shouldn't it be the same for blocking and non-blocking.

Comment: As a general rule, you should _always_ use a non-blocking assignment to variables in sequential `always` blocks that propagate outside the block. You will thank us later after you have written larger designs.

Answer (score 0):

Both are same.

Here is the relevant code snapshot.

```
module temp ();
  reg a, b;
  wire c, d;

  assign c = ({a, b} == 2'b10);
  assign d = (a & ~b);

  always @ (a, b)
  begin
    $display("------");
    $display("a = %0b, b = %0b, c = %0b", a, b, c);
    $display("a = %0b, b = %0b, d = %0b", a, b, d);
  end

  initial
  begin
    a = 1'b0; b = 1'b0;
#1  a = 1'b0; b = 1'b1;
#1  a = 1'b0; b = 1'bz;
#1  a = 1'b0; b = 1'bx;
#1  a = 1'b1; b = 1'b0;
#1  a = 1'b1; b = 1'b1;
#1  a = 1'b1; b = 1'bz;
#1  a = 1'b1; b = 1'bx;
#1  a = 1'bx; b = 1'b0;
#1  a = 1'bx; b = 1'b1;
#1  a = 1'bx; b = 1'bz;
#1  a = 1'bx; b = 1'bx;
#1  a = 1'bz; b = 1'b0;
#1  a = 1'bz; b = 1'b1;
#1  a = 1'bz; b = 1'bz;
#1  a = 1'bz; b = 1'bx;
  end
endmodule

// Output - 
------
a = 0, b = 0, c = 0
a = 0, b = 0, d = 0
------
a = 0, b = 1, c = 0
a = 0, b = 1, d = 0
------
a = 0, b = z, c = 0
a = 0, b = z, d = 0
------
a = 0, b = x, c = 0
a = 0, b = x, d = 0
------
a = 1, b = 0, c = 1
a = 1, b = 0, d = 1
------
a = 1, b = 1, c = 0
a = 1, b = 1, d = 0
------
a = 1, b = z, c = x
a = 1, b = z, d = x
------
a = 1, b = x, c = x
a = 1, b = x, d = x
------
a = x, b = 0, c = x
a = x, b = 0, d = x
------
a = x, b = 1, c = 0
a = x, b = 1, d = 0
------
a = x, b = z, c = x
a = x, b = z, d = x
------
a = x, b = x, c = x
a = x, b = x, d = x
------
a = z, b = 0, c = x
a = z, b = 0, d = x
------
a = z, b = 1, c = 0
a = z, b = 1, d = 0
------
a = z, b = z, c = x
a = z, b = z, d = x
------
a = z, b = x, c = x
a = z, b = x, d = x
------
```

**However if you use `===`, then the output will be different for `c` & `d`.**

Reason is that `===` also takes into account `1'bx` & `1'bz`, whereas `==` does not.

```
assign c = ({a, b} == 2'b10);
assign d = (a & ~b);

------
a = 1, b = z, c = 0
a = 1, b = z, d = x
```